# Increase in fsimage size by 1g over a period of 1 day

Tags: hadoop, namenode

fsimage size in hadoop cluster increased by 1G when there was no adhoc jobs run in one day . Need help how to check what caused the increase in size

Comment: What sort of things have you tried/checked already?

Comment: If any new tasks were added or huge data was copied to the cluster